# Jackson CsvMapper Bean not registering JavaTimeModule

Tags: kotlin, spring-bean, jackson-dataformat-csv

I recently attempted to use the Jackson CsvMapper and I found a peculiar "feature" that I think is a bug in the jackson lib. If I create a Spring bean for the mapper it appears to ignore the JavaTimeModule and the following error `Java 8 date/time type 'java.time.*' not supported by default` I substituted the class with '*' since all of the java time classes failed. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Here is my bean:

```
@Bean
fun csvMapper():CsvMapper = CsvMapper.builder()
        .enable(CsvParser.Feature.TRIM_SPACES)
        .enable(CsvParser.Feature.SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
        .addModule(JavaTimeModule()).build()
```

Here is a static instance in the class doing the processing that works as expected:

```
companion object {
    val csvMapper: CsvMapper = CsvMapper.builder()
    .enable(CsvParser.Feature.TRIM_SPACES)
    .enable(CsvParser.Feature.SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
    .addModule(JavaTimeModule()).build()
}
```

I have tried other modules as well, such as the KotlinModule and none of them seem to be registered correctly in the bean.

Answer (score 0):

How are you acquiring a reference to the Bean and the use-site?

I would bet that Spring is binding a different instance of `CsvMapper`.  Note  that `CsvMapper` is a subclass of `ObjectMapper`.

In the Spring variation of your application try commenting out that that bean declaration, or debug putting a breakpoint to find the object reference for the bean you *think* is being used and then another breakpoint at the use-site, etc, etc.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well, So I removed the bean definition to let the potential default Spring bean get injected but there was no default bean and the application failed to startup with a missing bean exception. Also to answer your first question, constructor injection.